# Google Sheets Script to Hide Row if Checkbox Checked

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hide, checked

I am trying to find a working code that will automatically hide a row if the checkbox in column F of that row is checked.

I have tried every script I have found and nothing seems to work. Unfortunately I am not code savvy and I am unable to find the issue.

This is what I currently have:

```
function onOpen() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Checklists");
  s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());

  s.getRange('F2:F200')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == "TRUE") 
      s.hideRows(i + 1);
    });
}
```

The sheet I am working on is "Checklists" and the column that contains the checkbox is F. The value of the checkbox is either TRUE or FALSE. If the value is TRUE, I want that row to be hidden.

Can someone please help!!!

Comment: How would the checkbox become unchecked (the value changed to `False`) so that the row will become un-hidden?

Comment: @PeterT I would not need to uncheck it. Once it is complete, I don't need to see it again however I don't want to delete it as we keep a record of everything.

Answer (score 1):

The quick test I was able to run was to set up a column of checkboxes in column F, then to create a function that catches each edit event on the sheet. This will immediately catch when the user checks a box and will then hide that row.

The trick with using the `onEdit` event is with determining which cell was actually changed. In your case, you only want to fully follow your logic if the change happens to a checkbox in column F. In my code, I've been using a function to make sure the change is in the desired range. The function looks like this:

```
function isInRange(checkRange, targetCell) {
  //--- check the target cell's row and column against the given
  //    checkrange area and return True if the target cell is
  //    inside that range
  var targetRow = targetCell.getRow();
  if (targetRow < checkRange.getRow() || targetRow > checkRange.getLastRow()) return false;

  var targetColumn = targetCell.getColumn();
  if (targetColumn < checkRange.getColumn() || targetColumn > checkRange.getLastColumn()) return false;

  //--- the target cell is in the range!
  return true;
}
```

So then all your `onEdit` function has to do is to make a quick call when the edit event is fired to see if the change falls within the range you're looking for. In this case, I set up a variable with my range to check:

```
var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var checkRange = thisSheet.getRange("F2:F200");  
if (isInRange(checkRange, eventObj.range)) {
```

After that, it's just a matter of picking the row number and hiding or showing. Here's the full example solution:

```
function isInRange(checkRange, targetCell) {
  //--- check the target cell's row and column against the given
  //    checkrange area and return True if the target cell is
  //    inside that range
  var targetRow = targetCell.getRow();
  if (targetRow < checkRange.getRow() || targetRow > checkRange.getLastRow()) return false;

  var targetColumn = targetCell.getColumn();
  if (targetColumn < checkRange.getColumn() || targetColumn > checkRange.getLastColumn()) return false;

  //--- the target cell is in the range!
  return true;
}

function onEdit(eventObj) {
  //--- you could set up a dynamic named range for this area to make it easier
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var checkRange = thisSheet.getRange("F2:F200");  
  if (isInRange(checkRange, eventObj.range)) {
    //--- so one of the checkboxes has changed its value, so hide or show
    //    that row
    var checkbox = eventObj.range;
    var rowIndex = checkbox.getRow();
    Logger.log('detected change in checkbox at ' + checkbox.getA1Notation() + ', value is now ' + checkbox.getValue());
    if (checkbox.getValue() == true) {
      Logger.log('hiding the row');
      thisSheet.hideRows(rowIndex, 1);
    } else {
      Logger.log('showing the row');
      thisSheet.showRows(rowIndex, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code can I make sure this is script is only effect sheet "Checklists"? @PeterT

Comment: In the `onEdit` function, after the first line that sets `thisSheet`, insert a line similar to this: `if (thisSheet.getSheetName() != 'Checklists') return;` This statement will immediately exit the function if it's not on the correct sheet.