# If Checkbox is checked, use a script to clear specified cells in row and clear checkbox after script is run

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a checkbox to run a script on the row it is in.  It needs to loop through all rows in the specified sheet.

If a checkbox is checked in Column F, I want to schedule a script to clear columns B-F.

B is a checkbox that should be set to FALSE
C is a data validated input
D is data validated input
E is a formula that relies on data in C and D.   The formula should remain.

F being true is the triggering checkbox

If F is checked, then clear contents in B,C,D, F  (E shouldnt be cleared since it's a formula)

I've tried modifying scripts from here and other links without success:

[Reset checkboxes to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185819/reset-checkboxes-to-false)

[Using a script to generate docs from rows in Google Sheet if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492799/using-a-script-to-generate-docs-from-rows-in-google-sheet-if-checkbox-is-checked)

[Google Sheets Script to Hide Row if Checkbox Checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316166/google-sheets-script-to-hide-row-if-checkbox-checked)

```
 function try_It(){
 deleteRow(5); //// choose col = 2 for column C, 5 for F
 }

 function deleteRowContents (col){ // col is the index of the column to check for checkbox being true

 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
 var targetData = new Array();
 for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
 if(data[n][col]!="TRUE" && data[n][col]!="FALSE"){ targetData.push(data[n])};
 }
 Logger.log(targetData);
 sh.getDataRange().clear();
 sh.getRange(1,1,targetData.length,targetData[0].length).setValues(targetData);
 }
```

Expected results:
If Column F is checked, clear B:F in same rows.(I know this script above is not even close to being complete).

Actual results:
This deletes all the formatting on the entire sheet.
It doesn't clear range properly even in the column F checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to clear the values of the column "B" to "D" and the column "F" when the checkbox of the column "F" is `true`.

  - In this case, you want to change the checkbox to `false`.
- You don't want to clear the cell format.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several solutions. The flow of the modified script is as follows.

- Create the range list for deleting the columns from the retrieved values.
- Clear the content of the range list.

#### Modified script:

```
function deleteRowContents (col){ // col is the index of the column to check for checkbox being true
  var col = 6; // If the column "F" is 6, please set 6.
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet4"); // Modified
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Below script was modified.
  var deleteRanges = data.reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (e[col - 1] === true) { // Modified
      return ar.concat(["B" + (i + 1) + ":D" + (i + 1), "F" + (i + 1)]);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (deleteRanges.length > 0) { // or if (deleteRanges.length) { // Added
    sh.getRangeList(deleteRanges).clearContent();
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)
- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#clearcontent)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: THANKS! This is amazing.  So helpful and beyond my skill level.  My only issue right now is -- if gives an error if there is nothing checked.  "Ranges must have at least one range. "  pointing to "deleteRanges"       If deleteRanges is null, how do I make it so it doesn't throw an error?

Comment: @B D Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thanks!! This mostly works flawlessly.  The only thing that is odd, is it deleted the headers from Row 6 which did not have a checkbox at all. 

Which part of this is checking for a checkbox?

Comment: Another issue -- how do I make it so it only works on Sheet4? or GetSheetByName?  SOmething like this : 


  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var tab4 = sh.getSheetByName('Sheet4')
  var data = tab4.getDataRange().getValues();

Comment: @B D I apologize again. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @B D I updated my answer for your added request. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: ISSUE 2 - It is clearing formulas for some reason.  I didn't think it was doing that at first... but now it is.



Another issue solved: Get Sheet by name to make it work on only one sheet is as follows:

 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4')

Comment: Thank you so much... the only outstanding issue now is, the formulas are getting removed... is there a way to NOT remove the formulas?

e.g. keep =if(D14=true, $G$3, )

Or can I get additional columns and just skip the one with a formula?

For example, I now want Column G to clear.

Comment: @B D I couldn't understand about ``is there a way to NOT remove the formulas? e.g. keep =if(D14=true, $G$3, )``. I apologize for my poor English skill. By the way, in the script of my answer, the column "F" (``var col = 6``) is not modified. So the formulas of the column "F" are not modified. From your question, I understood that you don't want to remove the formulas of the column "F" which is given by ``var col = 6``. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: THANKS -- I was able to just add more ranges with the concat statement, and skip the columns in which I wanted to keep formulas!  You are amazing

Comment: @B D Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Thanks so much again. I am still learning.  Question -- I also want to clear Column A for specified rows.  Like, also Column A for rows 123-145.

   if (e[col - 1] === true) {
      

      
      return ar.concat(["A123" + (i + 1) + ":A123" + (i + 1)]);


How can I do specified rows to clear additional columns?   Also thought about nesting an IF statement within the current if.  If row is between 123-145, also delete contents in column A.

Comment: @B D I would like to resolve your new question. But I couldn't understand about it. About this situation, I apologize for my poor English skill. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? I would like to think of about it. And also it will help a lot of users think of your solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Even if you cannot do, please don't worry.

Comment: Thank you -- I added a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070214/how-do-i-have-a-script-run-through-all-rows-with-checkboxes-but-have-it-do-some

Comment: @B D Thank you for replying. I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. When you comment to my answer, please comment it to my answer of your new question.